# How to disable Peek Definition when go to definition

Tags: visual-studio-code

My vsCode version is v1.24.1 , when I cilck go to definition, it go to the definition , at the same time it open peek definition, the peek definition is annoying,I just wonder to know how to disable it when I click go to definition.
ps: v1.23.1 don't has this problem.

Matt Bierner's answer could solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24861)

You can workaround it by manually upgrading your workspace to typescript@next by following [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions)

Comment: I didn't install typescript, so i don't think installing latest version of typescript can solve this problem, and [the bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24861) you indicated is not the same problem in my opinion. thank you anyway. PS: I rollback to version 1.23.1 , so i don't try the method you provide actually.

Comment: TypeScript powers VS Code's JavaScript intellisense too. Based on your description, I am pretty sure it is the same bug

Comment: I trid this method right now, and find it usless for my question.

Comment: When you run the  `Select typescript version` command in VS Code, is 3.0.0-insiders... selected?

Comment: wonderful, ctrl + shift + P ,then run Select typescript version,and select version 3.0.0, the problem is resolved. but there is still a little question. after I select version3.0.0 typescript, the absolute reference import will has a redundant ellipsis ...  under the path quotation marks.