# How can I disable the preview when go to definition in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I ever click to go to a definition in VS Code I just want to go there, I do not want the overlay.

Can I disable it?

[image]

Comment: There is `Peek Definition` that shows an overlay `Go to Definition` works fine for me. If you use `ctrl + left click` will it work as expected?

Comment: I am on a mac, I can't seem to get this combination going

Comment: I found that it's related with typescript. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51489

Comment: It will be fixed when ts 3.0 is released. There is also a workaround but I will just wait. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895227/how-to-disable-peek-definition-when-go-to-definition

Answer (score 51):

This happens when multiple definitions were found, modify `settings.json`

```
"editor.gotoLocation.multipleDefinitions": "goto"
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

So I was looking for the same thing and since I found this post and it wasn't answered yet, I thought I could do it.

vscode won't peek preview definitions anymore after you add this to your JSON user settings file:

```
"editor.gotoLocation.multiple": "goto"
```

Comment: VScode says, `This setting is deprecated, please use separate settings like 'editor.editor.gotoLocation.multipleDefinitions' or 'editor.editor.gotoLocation.multipleImplementations' instead.`

Answer (score 7):

Nothing of the above worked for me in solving this problem for a jsx file that imported from a typescript file.

- As mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993353/disable-preview-when-go-to-definition-in-vscode?rq=1#comment89424132_50993353), this was a typescript-related bug 3 years ago, which was seemingly fixed, but I guess it persists.

I solved it by going to <kbd>F1</kbd> > `Preferences: Open User Settings` > search for `peek` > try changing each setting to `goto` instead of `peek` and see what happens.

In my case, it was the `Multiple References` setting that's needed to be changed.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

By default VS Code shows this peek view with a list of definitions if there are more than one possible definitions for a given symbol. In your example, these are likely:

- The definition of `configurationCommon` in the restructured assignment
- The definition of `configurationCommon` in the required file

You can change this default behavior by setting `"editor.gotoLocation.multiple": "goto"`. This will jump directly to the definition. If there are multiple definitions, you can three press <kbd>f12</kbd> again to jump to the next one. A status bar item shows the total number of definitions while you do this:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, that has fixed my issue! Also, in 1.80.x this setting is deprecated in favor of 5 different settings: `"editor.gotoLocation.multipleDefinitions": "goto", "editor.gotoLocation.multipleDeclarations": "goto", "editor.gotoLocation.multipleImplementations": "goto","editor.gotoLocation.multipleReferences": "goto","editor.gotoLocation.multipleTypeDefinitions": "goto"`

Answer (score 4):

For the newer versions set:

**"editor.definitionLinkOpensInPeek": false**

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at the following settings (the below copied from defaultSettings.json):

> ```json
> // "editor.defaultColorDecorators": true,
> // "markdown.editor.pasteUrlAsFormattedLink.enabled": true,
> // Controls the behavior the 'Go to Declaration'-command when multiple target locations exist.
> //  - peek: Show Peek view of the results (default)
> //  - gotoAndPeek: Go to the primary result and show a Peek view
> //  - goto: Go to the primary result and enable Peek-less navigation to others
> "editor.gotoLocation.multipleDeclarations": "peek",
>
> // Controls the behavior the 'Go to Definition'-command when multiple target locations exist.
> //  - peek: Show Peek view of the results (default)
> //  - gotoAndPeek: Go to the primary result and show a Peek view
> //  - goto: Go to the primary result and enable Peek-less navigation to others
> "editor.gotoLocation.multipleDefinitions": "peek",
>
> // Controls the behavior the 'Go to Implementations'-command when multiple target locations exist.
> //  - peek: Show Peek view of the results (default)
> //  - gotoAndPeek: Go to the primary result and show a Peek view
> //  - goto: Go to the primary result and enable Peek-less navigation to others
> "editor.gotoLocation.multipleImplementations": "peek",
>
> // Controls the behavior the 'Go to References'-command when multiple target locations exist.
> //  - peek: Show Peek view of the results (default)
> //  - gotoAndPeek: Go to the primary result and show a Peek view
> //  - goto: Go to the primary result and enable Peek-less navigation to others
> "editor.gotoLocation.multipleReferences": "peek",
>
> // Controls the behavior the 'Go to Type Definition'-command when multiple target locations exist.
> //  - peek: Show Peek view of the results (default)
> //  - gotoAndPeek: Go to the primary result and show a Peek view
> //  - goto: Go to the primary result and enable Peek-less navigation to others
> "editor.gotoLocation.multipleTypeDefinitions": "peek",
> ```

Answer (score -1):

On my machine (Mac) if I press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + Click or <kbd>F12</kbd> on a method it will direct me to the Peek view on the definition, however <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> will direct me to the implementation without the peek appearing.

I tried to find a workaround changing the behavior of <kbd>CMD</kbd> + Click to go to implementation but it appears there is no solution yet?

The VSCode documentation shows its set by default to go to definition without a way to modify it:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved