# vscode "Go to definition" has inconsistent behavior

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed vscode on a a new system and the "Go to definition" behavior is not consistently doing what its suppose to. Meaning when I would use the "command + click" on macos on a function it would take me to the definition of the function. Now about 50% of the time it creates a split window in my editor that shows the definition of the function, but does actually take me to the file. The other 50% of the time it does what it has always done and navigates me to the file that has the function defined in and the line the function is defined on.

I see the value of this feature, but i don't want to replace the classic behavior of the "go to definition" function. Has anyone else seen this? How do i prevent this from happening?

Comment: is this not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50993353/11107541 ? if it is not, how?